# Не могу получить данные из базы данных(mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, pdo

Не могу получить данные из таблицы базы данных mysql, вместо массива данных строки таблицы, я получаю **false**. Что я делаю не так?

```
private function get_data_user($email) {
    $connect = $this->connect_database();
    $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $result->execute(array($email));
    $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    var_dump($result);
    $connect = null;
    return $result;
  }
```

И это очень странно. Этот же код работает:

```
public function authentication($email, $password) {
  $connect = $this->connect_database();
  $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
  $result->execute(array($email, $password));
  $result = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
  $connect = null;
  if($result) {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

P.s. я искал решение в поисковике, но не смог найти ответ.

Comment: попробуйте

$result = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
$result->execute(array('email' => $email));

Comment: Значит произошла какая-то ошибка, какая - можно выяснить через функцию `errorInfo`.

Comment: Я проверял через `errorInfo`, но он выдает **Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$result->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row = $result->fetch();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но проблема была не в самом методе, а в параметрах которые я передавал, во время того как я вызова метода. Я передавал название таблицы первым параметром, вместо **email**)

Comment: Хорошо, что разобрался, будь внимательней! )